# How to store spaces between variables in selenium ide

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a value in A say `A=Jack` and another value saved in B say `B=Johns`.
I need the output, Jack Johns. But I got the output like JackJohns.

```
javascript{storedVars['FirstName ']  +  storedVars[  'LastName']}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inset space, not just put space in index of `storedVars`:

```
javascript{storedVars['FirstName'] + ' ' + storedVars['LastName']}
```